# ldap query: ldapsearch for uniqueMember

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

How can I search for a *uniqueMember* in an objectClass *groupOfUniqueNames* within OpenLdap?

```
dn: cn=group,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: group
uniquemember: uid=member1
uniquemember: uid=member2
```

I've tried the following with no result:

> ldapsearch -x -b dc=example,dc=com "(uniqueMember=uid=member1)"

Pls help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The assertion used in this filter is probably not the full DN: `"(uniqueMember=uid=member1)"`. `uniqueMember` has DN syntax, therefore, the value used in the assertion must be a DN, for example: `(uniqueMember=uid=member1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com)`.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://web.archive.org/web/20120307075622/https://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](https://web.archive.org/web/20130702165700/http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Comment: Unfortunately, all of those links are dead. :-(

Comment: Edited to link "Search best practices" to archive.org.

Comment: Middle link is 404.

Comment: Updated "Mastering Search Filters" to point to archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20120307075622/https://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/

Answer (score 2):

Your query needs to be

"(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=uid=member1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com))"

something like that.